# Buttons sized incorrectly on iOS8, correctly on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, autolayout

I solved this before posting, but I'm sharing this anyway just in case it helps someone else.

I'm having a problem with certain buttons sizing incorrectly on iOS8.  They are coming out too tall, too wide, and the label is vertically misaligned.  Interestingly, though the button is x-centered on the signin view, it maintains alignment on the left side.  I'm still building on Xcode 5/iOS 7 as we have some higher priority issues we need to get out and building against iOS 8 breaks more than this.  Are there different constraints I can apply here?

I've included the background image slicing also.  It is 66x87 px, but the button is getting sized to 72px tall, so I'm not sure it is be related or not.

[image: Constraints]

[image: iOS 8]

[image: iOS 7]

[image: background image slicing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I did not have an @2x image for the button background.  The button background is just a flat color so there was no real need for an @2x before.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne This **is** the answer to the question (though it is deceptively short). Answers don't go in edits.